# How to fix error [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

1. Help to fix error:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<app-page-test>` - did you register
> the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
> provide the "name" option.
>
> (found in `<Root>`)

2. Why I dont see this component **app-page-test** in vue tools?

[image]

**Information.**

I added component to a custom page in the laravel project.

*test.blade.php*

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@push('scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/base/page/test/app.js') }}" defer></script>
@endpush

@section('content')
    <div id="pageTest">
        <app-page-test></app-page-test>
    </div>
@endsection
```

*resources/js/base/page/test/app.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './components/main';
import store from './store/index';

Vue.component(
    'app-page-test',
    App
);

new Vue({
    el: '#pageTest',
    store
});
```

*resources/js/base/page/test/components/main.vue*

```
<template>
    <div class="app-page-test">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "app-page-test",
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './components/main';
import store from './store/index';
Vue.component('app-page-test', require('./components/AppPageTest.vue').default);

new Vue({
    el: '#pageTest',
    store, 
});
```

Comment: Yes thank you. i deleted and re-created the whole project. The reason was never found, but now there are no errors.

Comment: @d-velop that' great so make sure you mark this answer so other will not spend time one this thanks

Comment: Hmm... the reason was never found. Even the source code works correctly in the new project. But thanks for trying to help.